# Publish Visual Studio extension to marketplace.visualstudio.com with TFS build pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I need to publish a Visual Studio extension to VS market place through the TFS CI build pipeline. I found following article on publishing extension to market place using command line, is there any deployment task in TFS which can use for this?

[Publish from the command line](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/publish/command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Visual Studio Team Services Developer Tools for Build and Release tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-developer-tools-build-tasks).

Make sure you generate the PAT with teh correct permissions. In order to publish extensions you'll need "Marketplace (Publish)", in order to install/share/query extensions you'll need further permissions. The required permissions are documented in the "Add Service" window.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing, I have came across an issue after adding the task to the build definition (TFS 2017) and raised an issue in git.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-build-release-tasks/issues/47

Comment: Hi @jessehouwing, I found the issue and its with the NodeJs path variable, however  I was not able to publish from my TFS to market place yet, I'm confused with the authentication option, how does the PAT token generated from local TFS 2017 server can authenticate for VS Marketplace? When execute build I get "error: Received response 401 (Not Authorized). Check that your personal access token is correct and hasn't expired."

Comment: I have followed these steps, can you confirm its correct: Generated a PAT token on VSTS with the correct scopes -> Created a VSTS Marketplace endpoint in TFS with VSTS PAT token ->  Used the created VSTS Marketplace endpoint in Publish extension.

Comment: Failing again with error:
Checking tfx under: C:\agent\_work\_tools\tfx.cmd
Found tfx under: C:\agent\_work\_tools\tfx.cmd
xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx exists true
error: Received response 401 (Not Authorized). Check that your personal access token is correct and hasn't expired.
tfx failed with error: Error: C:\agent\_work\_tools\tfx.cmd failed with return code: 4294967295

Account: All accessible accounts.
Scope: Marketplace (acquire)

Comment: Yes, it worked after adding scopes Marketplace (acquire),Marketplace (manage) and Marketplace (publish)

Comment: Is there a way to publish to market place without using the PAT token generated from VSTS account?

Comment: Thanks jessehouwing.

Comment: I'm getting following error, It seems everything is correct in manifest, can you help.
error: Failed Request: Bad Request(400) - Part URI is not valid per rules defined in the Open Packaging Conventions specification.
tfx failed with error: Error: C:\agent\_work\_tools\tfx.cmd failed with return code: 4294967295

Comment: Added the question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561554/vsts-developer-tools-build-tasks-error-part-uri-is-not-valid-per-rules-defined

Comment: Build task with updated manifest to support VS 2017 is getting failed, can you answer this please.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265733/vsts-developer-tools-build-task-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open?noredirect=1#comment75723475_44265733

Comment: Update: publish visual studio extension task has been added.