# VSTS Developer Tools Build Tasks Error: Part URI is not valid per rules defined in the Open Packaging Conventions specification

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm getting following error when executing VSTS Developer Tools Build Tasks, I have included extension manifest, Please help me to resolve this.

> error: Failed Request: Bad Request(400) - Part URI is not valid per
>   rules defined in the Open Packaging Conventions specification. tfx
>   failed with error: Error: C:\agent_work_tools\tfx.cmd failed with
>   return code: 4294967295 –

```
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="91abfa6b-b004-4d4c-9c70-xxxxxxx" Version="1.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="bandara" />
    <DisplayName>MyTestExt</DisplayName>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">VS Extension</Description>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[14.0]" />
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" Version="[4.5,)" />
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.14.0" DisplayName="Visual Studio MPF 14.0" Version="[14.0]" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" Path="MyTestExt.pkgdef" />
  </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

Comment: Ahh I'm so sorry, I was confused about the type of extension previously because of all the vs-team-services and vsts tags on your question. At the moment there is not yet a task to publish to the old Visual Studio Gallery. Though I'd expect support for the new marketplace soon. For now you still need to publish through https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/

Comment: The manifest file is the JSON file. I updated my answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding VSTS Developer Tools Build tasks, the manifest file is the JSON file instead of a XML file, you also could use VSIX file ([Published by tfx command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node#publish-your-extension)).

The JSON file likes this:

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "sample-extension",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "name": "My first sample extension",
    "description": "A sample Visual Studio Services extension.",
    "publisher": "fabrikamdev",
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
            }
        ],
    "icons": {
        "default": "images/logo.png"
     },
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "Fabrikam.HelloWorld",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
            "description": "Adds a 'Hello' hub to the Work hub group.",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-work-web.work-hub-group"
                ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "Hello",
                "order": 99,
                "uri": "hello-world.html"
            }
        }
    ],
    "scopes": [
        "vso.work"
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "hello-world.html", "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "scripts", "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "sdk/scripts", "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "images/logo.png", "addressable": true
        }
    ]
}
```

More information, you can refer to this article: [Your extension's manifest file: vss-extension.json](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node#your-extensions-manifest-file-vss-extensionjson)

My steps:

1. [Acquire a personal access token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/publish/command-line#acquire-a-personal-access-token) (make sure you select All accessible accounts) and add service endpoint
2. Edit/create build definition
3. Add npm install build step/task (working folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory);` npm command: `install`; arguments: `vss-web-extension-sdk`)
4. Add Publish Extension step/task (Check Extension manifest file option; Root manifest folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory);` Manifest file: `vss-extension.json`) **Note: My extension files are in source directory ($(Build.SourcesDirectory)), such as vss-extension.json etc…**