# VSTS Developer Tools Build Task Error: ENOENT: no > such file or directory, open > 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vsixeditorx\extension.vsomanifest

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm using "VSTS Developer Tools Build Task" to publish VS extension to VS market place from TFS build pipeline. I have configured the task in a test build pipeline installed in Windows 7 machine and it worked successfully, However, When I try to implement the same in a TFS 2017 server configured in Windows 2012 R2 machine, build task getting failed with following message, Pleas help me to resolve this issue.

**Log:**

> 2017-05-30T14:08:29.9662395Z ##[section]Starting: Publish Extension
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.3822685Z Checking tfx under:
>   C:\agent_work_tools\tfx.cmd 2017-05-30T14:08:30.3842666Z Found tfx
>   under: C:\agent_work_tools\tfx.cmd 2017-05-30T14:08:30.3902665Z
>   fb1f75e8-b06a-414f-bed5-668a1a1b62f9 exists true
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4122731Z
>   [command]C:\agent_work_tasks\PublishExtension_xxxxxx-50ab-47c8-b766-7ae2aa672733\1.1.44\node_modules\7zip-bin-win\x64\7za.exe
>   x C:\test\MyVSExtension.vsix
>   -oC:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vsixeditor117430-13304-9r8956 -y -spd -aoa 2017-05-30T14:08:30.4712737Z  2017-05-30T14:08:30.4722738Z 7-Zip (a) [64] 16.04 : Copyright (c)
>   1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-10-04 2017-05-30T14:08:30.4722738Z 
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4722738Z Scanning the drive for archives:
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4722738Z 1 file, 1317288 bytes (1287 KiB)
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4722738Z  2017-05-30T14:08:30.4722738Z Extracting
>   archive: C:\test\MyVSExtension.vsix 2017-05-30T14:08:30.4722738Z --
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4732733Z Path = C:\test\MyVSExtension.vsix
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4732733Z Type = zip 2017-05-30T14:08:30.4732733Z
>   Physical Size = 1317288 2017-05-30T14:08:30.4732733Z 
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4732733Z Everything is Ok
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4732733Z  2017-05-30T14:08:30.4732733Z Files: 13
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4732733Z Size:       1315278
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4732733Z Compressed: 1317288
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4812847Z ##[error]Error occurred before preparing
>   to run tfx: Error determining tasks manifest paths: Error: ENOENT: no
>   such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vsixeditor117430-xxxxx-9r8956\extension.vsomanifest'
>   2017-05-30T14:08:30.4962729Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish Extension

**Extension Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx" Version="1.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="Bandara" />
    <DisplayName>My Extension</DisplayName>
    <Description xml:space="preserve">My Extension Description</Description>
    <License>Resources\License.txt</License>
    <Icon>Resources\32x32icon.png</Icon>
    <PreviewImage>Resources\200x200logo.png</PreviewImage>
    <Tags>Tag X</Tags>
  </Metadata>
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[14.0,15.0]" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />
  </Installation>
  <Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.5,)" />
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.14.0" DisplayName="Visual Studio MPF 14.0" d:Source="Installed" Version="[14.0]" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%|" />
  </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

**Files inside .vsix**
[image]

Comment: Did you manually check the path `C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vsixeditor117430-xxxxx-9r8956` ? Could you find the  extension.vsomanifest file? Make sure your build service account have enough permission of the file path on the build agent.

Comment: Which extension you'd like to publish? The task is used to publish VSTS extension.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT: The Manifest file is not available in the C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\vsixeditor117430-xxxxx‌​-9r8956 folder.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT: I'm publishing a Visual Studio extension (Not a VSTS extension), We ware able to use this to publish the VS extension in a test environment. Following is the reference we used to select this build task.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345556/publish-visual-studio-extension-to-marketplace-visualstudio-com-with-tfs-build-p/42346153?noredirect=1#comment72254708_42346153

Comment: @Bandara That's wired since the files in VS Extension is different with VSTS Extension. It is extension.vsixmanifest in VS Extension.  Can you share the build logs on test environment?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT: I'm sorry Eddie, the test machine is cleared so we don't have the logs anymore. But I'm sure I have published the VS extension to marketplace via the VSTS Developer Tools Build Task.

Comment: @jessehouwing: may be you can help us sort this out :)

Comment: @Bandara Then can you share the manifest in the VS extension that you published via the task?

Comment: @Bandara No "extension.vsomanifest" file in the vsix?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT: Yes Eddie. I have attached a screen shot offiles list in .vsix

Comment: @Bandara The VSTS Developer Tools use tfx cli to publish the packages. What's the result if you use tfx cli to publish the vsix file manually?

Comment: The build task you're using only works with Team Services and TFS extensions, not with Visual Studio extensions. I've at lest never tested it with Visual Studio extensions. It may work in Publish from Manifest mode, but when using the Publish from VSIX mode, it will not be able to update the manifest, because a Visual Studio extension doesn't have the expected manifest files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTS Developer Tools Build Task cannot be used to publish VS extensions, There is no build task for this at the moment.